# OnClick Javascript Custom Button Pre-populating input workaround

Tags: javascript, lightning

I have the onclick javaScript custom clone which has a functionality that populates a custom field called "Cloned From".

Upon click of Clone button, on create record layout, the "Clone From" will be populated by the Record ID of the Original Record. Since this is not supported on Lightning Experience, we would like to know if there is a workaround kind of behavior?

Comment: You need to share your code if you want an answer to why it doesn't work.

Comment: @RobertSussland here is code for the onclick javscript clone button. "00NC0000005Ijne" is sa custom field. `parent.location.href = '/{!Campaign.Id}/e?clone=1&retURL=%2F{!Campaign.Id}&00NC0000005Ijne={!Campaign.Id}' `

Comment: Ahh, OK. URL hacking like this doesn't work in Lightning, but you can call actions that achieve this. See https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/lex_migration_customization/lex_migration_customization_actions

Comment: @RobertSussland how will i use clone functionality on actions?

Comment: You have to write your own component as per the answer below, but *instead* of including a script block to populate the record id, if you component implements force:hasRecordId, then it will be given the record id automatically. See here for sample code: https://andyinthecloud.com/2016/08/21/winter17-using-a-lightning-component-from-an-action/

Answer (score 1):

Create a visualforce page for selected object. e.g:- for contact object

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" >
<script>
    var id= "{!record.id}";
    console.log(id);
</script>
```

then you can pass this id to a component. which will create a cloned record.

you have to create a new action button on contact which will open above page and then add it to the page layout.

Comment: @Manjos - what specific component i need to create to pass the record ID?

Comment: $Lightning.createComponent("c:creteClone",{
             "id" : id
        },"lightning",function(cmp) {});

Comment: you have to create a new LightningComponent which will get id of record as parameter and make clone of that record.

Comment: <aura:component controller="cloneRecord">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="id" type="String" />

Comment: <aura:component controller="cloneRecord">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="id" type="String" />            </aura:component>

Comment: controller of component ({
 doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
  var action = component.get("c.clone");
        action.setParams({"id"  : id, 
                          
                         });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                
            }
            else {
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
 }
})

Comment: you will need to write class with cloneRecord name . this link will help http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58078/cloning-record-with-visualforce-apex

Comment: Thanks Manjot! I will try all these references, and will update you here.

Comment: Is it possible to display clone layout pop-up with all the fields of the original record and then have the choice to save/insert or not?